# pull data from two tables with one query/ select statement

Tags: php, sql

I am pulling one column from the USERS table but now I wanna pull columns from the MONEY table. How do I accomplish this?

sample database

USERS TABLE
userID = 33 
nestEgg = 600000

MONEY TABLE 
userID = 33
monthlyContributions = 500, 250, 300
totalContributions =

```
     <?php
     include 'inc/connect.php';
     $query = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE userID = '$userID'";
     $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
     ?>
```

Comment: you should have a link between the two tables. Like a foreign key. How is your database schema like?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. Can you share the schema of the two tables and your desired results? This is either a job for `JOIN` or `UNION` but your needs and schema will dictate that.

Comment: I have a foreign key. userID is primary in USERS table and the foreign key of the MONEY table.

Comment: You can accomplish this with the JOIN operator in MySQL. You're probably best of with some reading material. https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: Add sample table data for both tables, and the combined result. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: I am trying to take the sum of a column (monthlyContribution) in the MONEY table and display it as totalContribution. The reason i need to join tables is because i have a column (nestEgg) in the USERS table i also need to pull. This is all for a retirement calculator.

Comment: Sample table data and expected result still needed.

Comment: Please, add the structure of both tables for us. Then we could help how to join it correctly. Moreover, try to create a query and provide it too.

Comment: Is it possible to select all from both tables? I am going to need to pull a lot of data from the money table

Comment: @seanvitale If you join the tables and select all, you still need to assign the right records on both end. Ie... Does record 1 of table 1 belong to record 10 of table 2? .. That is where you need a foreign key. So in a way the answer is you can get all of both tables, but there must be a condition.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you're asking to create a column in MONEY which is the sum of nestEgg and monthlyContributions. I'm a total newbie, but I think getting the sum, followed by the insert, should look like:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(nestEgg) FROM USERS) + (SELECT SUM(monthlyContributions) FROM MONEY)
INSERT INTO MONEY(totalContributions)
```

If you only want the sum from the monthly contributions, then it should just be:

```
SELECT SUM(monthlyContributions) FROM MONEY
INSERT INTO MONEY(totalContributions)
```

If I'm not mistaken.

Comment: No, I have a column in MONEY called totalContribution which should be the sum of monthlyContributions only